# Identificar esquinas no Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocalização

Estou desenvolvendo uma app Android que utilizará mapas enquanto o usuário dirige o carro. Preciso saber se é possível utilizar a posição corrente do usuário e identificar as esquinas próximas a essa posição.

É possível fazer isso? Como?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574839/google-maps-android-api-v2-getvisibleregion-returns-0

Comment: Eu preciso de algo do tipo: estou na Rua B, a próxima rua a frente é a Rua C e a anterior é  a Rua A, ou seja, essas ruas fazem esquina com o trecho da rua que estou atualmente.